# Using fuseki to run sparql queries against large TTL files locally

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I would like to run / optimize sparql queries on my local machine against a large (~15GB) .ttl file. Because the file is so large, I am thinking that I should upload the file somewhere like a local server that can also accept my sparql queries and run it against the loaded .ttl data. I came across Fuseki and it seems to be exactly what I want, but based on the documentation it looks as if the entire RDF .ttl file is stored in memory when you upload it. I don't think this would work for my use case as I need to run everything locally. Is this the recommended approach or is there a better way to test sparql queries against large RDF data stores locally?

Comment: that is not correct. Fuseki is just the HTTP layer on top of several backends. Besides an in-memory SPARQL engine it also supports a disk based  backend (TDB/TDB2). Indeed, a triple store is the way to go, just try it out

Comment: So many possibilities for a local triple store.... Including my own employer's offering, [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), of which you're probably most interested in the [Open Source Edition](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex).  Note that SPARQL query optimization depends somewhat on the SPARQL processor you're using, so if you know what that will be, you may want to start with it now, whether Fuseki, Virtuoso, or otherwise.